# Pagination links not working in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

controller:

```
public function management_colleges($offset=null)
{
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'management_college'; 
    $total = $this->field->management_count();
    $config['total_rows'] = $total['count_rows']; 
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination" id="search_page_pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = FALSE;
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = FALSE;
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['management'] = $this->field->management($config['per_page'],$offset);
    $this->load->view('management-colleges', $data);
}
```

view:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="body">
        <ul id="ul">
            <?php
                foreach ($management as $fetch) 
                {
            ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php echo $fetch['college_name']; ?>
                    </li>
            <?php   
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
            echo $this->pagination->create_links();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('body').on('click','ul#search_page_pagination>li>a',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var Pagination_url = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url:Pagination_url,
                type:'POST',
                success:function(data){
                    var $page_data = $(data);
                    $('#container').html($page_data.find('div#body'));
                    $('#ul').addClass('ul');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Model:

```
 public function management($limit, $start) 
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('colleges');
    $where = "field = 'management'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

In this code I have create an ajax pagination where I don't want to reload my page. I want to show data without refreshing page when click on pagination links thats why I am using ajax pagination. Here, I have created ajax pagination Links of pagination are showing but When I click on that link then nothing happen Page remain same. So, I don't Know where I am doing wrong can any body help me out to fix this issue ?Please help.

Thank You

Comment: can any one hep me out ?

Comment: Check https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/AJAX-Pagination-with-CI-Pagination-Library and https://www.codexworld.com/ajax-pagination-in-codeigniter-framework/